# Counting the lines of code in a file in c++ with skipping lines with only comments or blank lines

Tags: c++, count, comments, line, skip

I'm currently working on a program that loads a file and then reads back the number of lines to the user.  I just need some help on when to have program count a line or not. Currently I have:

```
getline(file, line);
if(line.empty() || line.find("//") || line.find("**") || line.find("/*") || line.find("*/"))
{ skip line }
```

The only problem is the program won't count a line if it still has code but has a comment (any of the following examples):

```
code...  //comment
code... /* comment
/* comment */ code...
```

Any tips or help?

Comment: What about `std::cout << "//" << std::endl;` and `int** ptr`

Comment: you just cannot count lines like that (well you can but it will be wrong). What about multi-line `/* */` comments? You need a lexer / tokenizer and memorize the states you're in (comment or not).

Comment: It's a good beginner programming exercise. Build a simple state machine to track the status of your walk through the text.

Comment: If you are not doing this for the lulz, gcc can just remove the comments for you with `-fpreprocessed` and the rest is a piece of cake.

Comment: Note that `std::string::find()` returns `std::string::npos` which is guaranteed to be a non-zero value (typically it is `-1` converted to `std::string::size_type`). That is, your test yields `true` if the sought string is **not** on the line. My personal approach would be to skip leading whitespace before reading the line (using `if (std::getline(in >> std::ws, line)) { ... }` and then checking whether the comment happens on column zero. Of course, I would also properly find the end of a comment starting with `/*` instead of relying on any specific formatting on the subsequent lines....

Comment: Use a tool (like [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/)) that implements a parser for this already. Parsing comments may not look like a terribly challenging task. However, it is. Consider code like `//*`, which (depending on the order of evaluation) may wrongfully be interpreted as the start of a block comment. You'd also need to exclude parsing of character string literals, and likely `#include` directives as well. This really is harder, than it looks.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: [-fpreprocessed](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) doesn't appear to strip blank lines (which the OP is asking for as well). Or am I misinterpreting the documentation?

Comment: Use http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/ since it is quite known.

Comment: @IInspectable Afaik it doesn't strip blank lines, but those are easy to identify anyways. It does solve the hard part of the task though.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm for accomplishing what you need could be as follows:
(Note: This code is untested)

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
//collect all the lines in the vector

//iterate through the vector, removing all leading and trailing whitespace characters
for(auto& line : lines)
{
  std::string::size_type pos = line.find_last_not_of("\n\t ");
  if(pos != std::string::npos)
    line.erase(pos + 1)

  pos = line.find_first_not_of("\n\t ");
  if(pos != std::string::npos && pos != 0)
    line.erase(0, pos);
}

//remove all comment-only lines and blank lines
bool comment_block = false;
lines.erase(std::remove_if(lines.begin(), lines.end(), [&comment_block](const std::string& line){
  //if it's empty, remove it
  if(line.empty())
    return true;

  //if it starts with "//" it can't have code after it
  if(line.find("//") == 0)
    return true;

  //if it starts with "/*", it begins a comment block
  //(or if we're already in a comment block from earlier...)
  if(comment_block || line.find("/*") == 0)
  {
    auto pos = line.find("*/");
    if(pos == std::string::npos)
    {
      //if we can't find "*/" in this line, this is a comment block
      //so this line is all comments and it continues to the next line
      comment_block = true;
      return true;
    }
    //if we did find "*/" in this line, we are no longer in a comment block
    //(if we were already)
    comment_block = false;
    //Also, if "*/" is the last thing in this line, it's all comments
    return pos == line.length() - 2;
  }

  return false;
}), lines.end());
```

Comment: No, sorry, it ain't that easy. Your algorithm will tag `cout << "//";` as a comment line. Not as bad as the other answer, but still doesn't do what has been asked for. For the love of God, don't try to roll your own. Use a tool that has been designed for this purpose. This is **way** more involved than you make it look like.

Comment: @IInspectable Nah, it won't tag `cout << "//"` as a comment line as in my algorithm `//` must be at the beginning of the line (after whitespaces have been removed). Same with `/*`

Comment: That may actually be true. It still fails to reliably test for the end of a block comment. `cout << "*/";` will wrongfully terminate a block comment. And it will fail to reliably find the beginning of a block comment, if it starts anywhere but the beginning of a line. This is certainly not desirable.

Comment: @IInspectable This is true. And, there's another problem with it I now see... Well, as I disclaimed, this code's untested. Hopefully it'll give the OP more of an idea of all that's needed, though.

Comment: This doesn't cover anything but the most trivial cases. I don't see, how that could possibly *"give the OP more of an idea of **all** that's needed"*. It doesn't even mention string literals, less so attempts to parse them. And it doesn't work reliably for the trivial cases either (inside a block comment, `//*/` will not be recognized as the end of the block comment either). You'll have to put in a lot more effort, to produce something helpful, and if you find that you need to post *"untested"* code, you might be better off, suggesting a tool instead.